# Implement polling mechanism within a JavaScript promise chain

Tags: es6-promise

I am writing a `node.js (v12.13.0)` script that involves a REST API. Imagine the following sequence of tasks, to be performed in the same order:

```
Task 1
 |
User Action
 |
Task 2
 |
Task 3
```

- `Task 1` => obtain a 5-digit alphanumeric code (valid for *10 mins*) by calling the REST API
- `User Action` => user enters aforementioned alphanumeric code in a web browser
- `Task 2` => obtain an OAuth2 authorization code by calling the REST API; if the `User Action` step is not completed, the REST API will return an error response
- `Task 3` => obtain OAuth2 tokens by calling the REST API after the authorization code is received as as a result of completing `Task 2`

`User Action` and `Task 2` must be completed within *10 minutes* of the generation of the 5-digit alphanumeric code in `Task 1`. Since Tasks 1, 2 and 3 are performed within a script, there is no way of knowing exactly when a user completes `User Action`. So, the only option is for `Task 2` to *repeatedly* call the REST API until an OAuth2 authorization code is generated. If 10 minutes has elapsed and the REST API continues to yield an error, then the script must stop since it cannot perform `Task 3`.

I tried implementing this using JavaScript's `Promise` (ES 6) and `setInterval` along the following lines:

```
const fnPerformTask1 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    /*
      code goes here, to call REST API and obtain a 5-digit alphanumeric code
     */

    resolve({
      "code": "<5_digit_apha_code>"
      "genTime": new Date()
    })
  });
}

const fnPerformTask2 = (task1Result) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    /*
      (a) code goes here, to call REST API and obtain an OAuth2 authorization code
      (b) if REST API returns error _and_ 10 minutes have not yet elapsed, repeat step (a)
     */
    resolve(<authorization_code>);
  });
}

const fnPerformTask3 = (task2Result) => {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
    /*
      code goes here, to call REST API and obtain OAuth2 tokens
     */
    resolve(<tokens>);
  });
}

fnPerformTask1()
  .then(fnPerformTask2)
  .catch(console.error) // if Task 2 fails, break out of this promise chain and don't perform Task 3
  .then(fnPerformTask3)
  .then(console.info)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Can I implement some kind of a *poll-like mechanism* in `Task 2`, using `Promise` and `setInterval`, and clear the interval when either the REST API returns an authorization code, or 10 minutes has elapsed without receiving an authorization code... presumably because the user did not complete `User Action` within 10 minutes?

A second, related question is how do I break out of a promise chain if Task 2 cannot be completed?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I break out of a promise chain if Task 2 cannot be completed?

```
fnPerformTask1()
.then(fnPerformTask2)
.catch(err => throw err) // this will break the promise chain and the control will move to subsequent .catch()
.then(fnPerformTask3)
.then(console.info)
.catch((err) => console.log("potential error thrown from fnPerformTask2"));
```